# Convert XX to 20XX text date in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have cells with this format:
1/feb/12
And I format cells as date xx/xx/xxxx like this:

```
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Replace What:="-", Replacement:="/", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
```

But when I execute it, Excel shows a warning: "Text date with 2 digit year" and shows me some options, I want the one that says "Convert XX to 20XX text date in VBA". This happens because the year is 12 and it asks if it is 1912 or 2012.
I want my vba macro to say "it is 2012".

Some way?? If I do the same "replace" manually (not on vba) the 2012 is automatically updated, but I need this automatic.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Finally solved with this:

```
 'Pasa los años XX a 20XX
Private Sub FormatAny()
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
For Each celda In Range(Range("A1"), Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1))
    If Len(celda.Text) > 4 Then
        Dim divTexto: divTexto = Split(celda.Text, "/")
        If UBound(divTexto) - LBound(divTexto) = 2 Then
            If Len(divTexto(UBound(divTexto))) = 2 Then
                divTexto(UBound(divTexto)) = "20" & divTexto(UBound(divTexto))
                celda = Join(divTexto, "/")
                Range("A" & i).Select
                ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = celda
            End If
        End If
    End If
i = i + 1
If (i = 32676) Then
    Exit For
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for each c in range(range("A1"), cells(activesheet.rows.count,1))
dim s$:s=c.text
if len(s)>4 then

dim a : a=split(s,"/")
if ubound(a)-lbound(a) = 2 then 
if len(a(ubound(a)))=2 then 
a(a(ubound(a)))="20" & a(a(ubound(a)))
c=join(a,"/")
' or !     c=cdate(join(a,"/"))
end if
end if
end if
next
```

Comment: Thanks but i don't see the "end ifs" and the line
     "dim a() : a=split(s,"/")" doesn't work, compiler says it is because the variable type

Comment: yes I guess you'll be able to add it :) I modify the code

Comment: That was fast! thanks! Now I get this error in "If Len(a(2)) = 2 Then _
    c = DateSerial(CLng("20" & a(2)), a(1), a(0))". The error says: RunTime Error 9, Index out of interval

Comment: I guess you have a cell which is not a date. I update the code :D

Comment: Same error, but at second iteration this time.
The range of dates is from A2 to A...
The fields contains: 1/ene/12 , 31/dic/12 , etc.
My code at question is executed before this.

Comment: the format is  01/02/03 or 01/Jan/03? (edited: yep it is in the question I'll edit my answer :D

Comment: it didn't show me any error but it dind't do anything either

Comment: New version: if your vectors are base 1 it should do it... Try a line by line debug

Comment: errors: RunTime Error 9, Index out of interval at line: a(a(UBound(a))) = "20" & a(a(UBound(a)))... The first "a" on the line and the first "a" after the "&" are out of interval. On the other hand, c=join(a,"/") is not changing the real value on the cell, but sometimes it has the correct value. How could I assign the value in "c" to the cell?